# Prove or Disprove X and Y and independent

Tags: probability

Intuitively, I think I understand how they are not independent. However, I am struggling in finding a acceptable proof method. Very new to proofs and probability. Any help would be great!

Suppose you roll n≥1 fair dice.  Let X be the random variable for the sum of their values,  and let Y be the random variable for the number of times an odd number comes up. Prove or disprove: X and Y are independent

Comment: Well, if you know that an odd number comes up $≥1$ times then the sum can not be $6n$ (just for one example).

Comment: If you roll the die 16 times, and the first fifteen are 6 (which implies x=0 or x=1), the sum must be composite.

Comment: Hint: $X$ is even if and only if $Y$ is even.